# Remote SQL Server DB backup

Tags: sql-server, backup

How do I backup data on a remote MS-SQL Server to my local computer?

I'm having access to Management Studio 2008. But I am willing to do anything ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you do something like

```
BACKUP DATABASE <dbName> TO DISK = '<path>'
RESTORE DATABASE <dbName> FROM DISK = '<path>'
```

Have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q314546

there is also a tool called sqldump

http://sqldump.sourceforge.net/